# $f(\lambda) = max\left \{ (c + D\lambda)^{t}x : x \in P \right \}$. is convex.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, D \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times p}, b \in \mathbb{R}^{m} $ and $c \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Define $$P =\left \{ x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n} : Ax=b , \forall_i \text{ } x_i \geq 0 \right \}$$ Suppose that $P$ is not empty and limited (bounded). Define a function $$f(\lambda) = max\left \{ (c + D\lambda)^{t}x : x \in P \right \}$$
I would like to show that $f((1-\alpha)\lambda^1 + \alpha\lambda^2) \geq (1-\alpha)f(\lambda^1) + \alpha.f(\alpha^2), $ for every $\alpha \in \left [ 0,1 \right ], \lambda^1, \lambda^2 \in \mathbb{R}^p$.

I don't know how can do this, because $f$ is a function of $\lambda$. 
I would appreciate any kind of help.

Proof idea

Define $F_x({\lambda}) = (c + D\lambda)^T. $ where $ D \in \mathbb{R}^p$

Given $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^p$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$
$F_x((1-\alpha)\lambda_1 + \alpha\lambda_2)$ =

$(c + D(1-\alpha)\lambda_1 + \alpha\lambda_2)^{T}x)$

= $(c^T + [D(1-\alpha)\lambda_1]^T + [D\alpha\lambda_2)^{T}])x$

= $(c^{T}x + (1-\alpha)\lambda_1^{T}D^{T}x + \alpha \lambda_{2}^{T}D^{T}x
$

= $(c^Tx + (1-\alpha)\lambda_1^{T}D^{T}x) + (c^Tx + \alpha \lambda_{2}^{T}D^{T}x)$

...

= $F_x((1-\alpha)\lambda_1) + F_x(\alpha\lambda_2)$

= $(1-\alpha)F_x(\lambda_1) + \alpha F_x(\lambda_2)$

I need help with some steps.

Comment: What does it mean that $x\geq 0$ when $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$? Do you mean that each coordinate is non-negative? Also what do you mean by "limited"? What is $P$ and how is it related to $P(\lambda)$?

Comment: Yes, each coordinate is non-negative and P is bounded

Comment: ok, is $P$ related to $P(\lambda)$? If so how, and if not then why did you define $P(\lambda)$ at all?

Comment: I think it's the values ​​of x that are vertices of the polyhedron. This is a question on Linear programming. Sorry, i need a big mistake, P is not function of Lambda

Comment: 1. Prove that $F_x(\lambda)=(c+D\lambda)^tx$ is convex. 2. Prove (or use the fact) that maximum of convex functions is convex.

Comment: I need some method to separate (c+Dλ)

Comment: The crucial part of the separation is $c=(1-\alpha)c+\alpha c$. Then $$c + D(1-\alpha)\lambda_1 + D\alpha\lambda_2=(1-\alpha)(c+D\lambda_1)+\alpha(c+D\lambda_2).$$